# GitLab shows deleted branches

Tags: git, git-branch, gitlab

I have a problem with showing branches in GitLab.  Between displayed branches there are two which were deleted. I believe it is because of their name `origin/ondrat/xxxxx` and `origin/vladan/xxxxx`. So the full path pathspec is `origin/origin/ondtrat...`. These two branches will not appear in the listing `git branch -r` and in GitLab UI can not be deleted. When i try delete them in GitLab, nothing happens.
Is there a way to eliminate them or is it a bug?

Comment: Have you tried `git push origin --delete branchname`?

Comment: Yes, i tried, but:  remote ref does not exist

Comment: You should be able to add a remote with `git remote add gitlab <url>`. Then try deleting with `git push gitlab --delete branchname`. Or did you already do that and it doesn't work?

Comment: The same error: remote ref does not exist

Comment: That is strange. I'm afraid I don't have any more ideas...

Comment: Sorry man, that worked. I made a mistake in the name of the branch, thx a lot.

Comment: @rws If you write your solution as an answer it should make it easier for anyone else having the same problem to spot it. Especially if Hekimen accepts it as the answer and some of us up vote it.

Comment: @PeterSW I think it was more a case of an unknown or weird branchname than anything because `push <remote> --delete <branchname>` is just the standard command to delete remote branches, but okay.

Comment: @rws Can you pls add to answer trick with `git remote add gitlab <url>`. Now i can't accept answer, because this not working, when the branch starts with the same name as remote repo name...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ git remote add gitlab <url>
$ git push gitlab --delete <branchname>
```

Answer (score 9):

As a colleague (the in-house `GitLab` maintainer) explained, `the branches are gone but the tracking information is not.` To get rid of the tracking information:

Option 1

```
$ git fetch --prune
```

Option 2 (on a clean branch)

```
$ git merge --prune
```

#### Background

I faced a somewhat similar situation where the remote branch was deleted after merging into master, and I deleted the local branch, but the remote branch still showed up in `git branch -a`

```
[samveen@development opsgenie_webhook]$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/submodules
  remotes/origin/update1
```

Further, on checkout, the state of the repo is `detached HEAD`:

```
[samveen@development opsgenie_webhook]$ git checkout  remotes/origin/submodules
M   libs
Note: checking out 'remotes/origin/submodules'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at 6d9727e... Add target first_init
```

Comment: --prune was what I was looking for. Had old stuff locally not reflected on remote. THanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried pushing an "empty" branch ? 
Like ***git push origin :origin/ondrat/xxxxx*** ?